# Getting a part of a string in java

Tags: java, string

so, right now I have this String:

```
String csfo = "([csfo_num = 333015303][ csfo_minimum = 4044504600][ csfo_offering = 48526][csfo_add_ind A])";
```

I want to be able to get just this part of the the string but I'm at a loss as to how to do this.

Needed Output:

```
String[] requiredOutput;
requiredOutput[1] =  48526; // csfo_offering
requiredOutput[2] = csfo_add_ind A;
```

or

```
requiredOutput[2] = A; // csfo_add_ind
```

---

EDIT: 
I have used some of your suggestions and am trying out subString but it seems like its a temp fix because if the length of the original string changes then it will throw a wrench in my calls. I will try regex next because it seems to go by pattern matching and I might be able to figure something out with that. Thanks everyone for all your help.

Suggestions are still appreciated!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Comment: don't you need quotations marks?

Comment: `String csfo = ([csfo_num = 333015303][ csfo_minimum = 4044504600][ csfo_offering = 48526][csfo_add_ind A]);` - i'm not ure that compiles

Comment: yes, sorry forgot about. obviously that wouldn't compile lol..

Comment: How about using regular expressions if the string follows the same pattern ?

Comment: regular expressions? I will have to look into that, thank you! I have used string substring right now but its a temp fix because if the length of the string changes then it will cause problems but regular expressions seem to avoid that issue as it goes by pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Are the numbers always the same length? If so, use `String.subString`. If not use `String.indexOf("csfo_add")` to find the locations of the "csfo_add" parts and then find the relative locations of the required information.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there you can also use `split` if you always have the same pattern for your string.

for example

```
    String csfo = "([csfo_num = 333015303][ csfo_minimum = 4044504600][ csfo_offering = 48526][csfo_add_ind A])";
    System.out.println(csfo.split("csfo_add_ind ")[1].split("\\]\\)")[0]);
```

Would get the `requiredOutput[2] = A; // csfo_add_ind`

and this would get the first one

```
    String[] requiredOutput = new String[2];
    String csfo = "([csfo_num = 333015303][ csfo_minimum = 4044504600][ csfo_offering = 48526][csfo_add_ind A])";
    requiredOutput[0] = "csfo_add_ind " + csfo.split("csfo_add_ind ")[1].split("\\]\\)")[0];
    requiredOutput[1] = csfo.split("\\]\\[csfo_add_ind ")[0].split("csfo_offering = ")[1];
    //System.out.println(requiredOutput[0] + " et " + requiredOutput[1] );
```